# Zuul Gateway not forwarding call to Eureka registered Instance

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have spent days on this simple issue , I am giving up and finally posting this issue which I am facing locally. I am trying to set up a microservices flow in my local for my hand itching learning purpose. This is no brainer. I have Eureka , Zuul Gateway , Simple Microservice. When I try to reach to the underlying service with the "url route" its working. But when I try to do serviceId look up its not working. Guys help me fixing it.

Git hub link is [Git hub source code link](https://github.com/kbjan26/microservice-skeleton)

I have also raised an issue [Git hut Issue link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3671)

Eureka Screenshot

[image: PostMan 404 Error]

Zuul Gateway logs

2019-10-06 11:11:24.611 INFO 26980 --- [nio-2020-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-10-06 11:11:24.611 INFO 26980 --- [nio-2020-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-10-06 11:11:24.633 INFO 26980 --- [nio-2020-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed initialization in 22 ms
2019-10-06 11:11:25.103 INFO 26980 --- [nio-2020-exec-4] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty : Flipping property: CHECKOUT-SERVICE.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2019-10-06 11:11:25.157 INFO 26980 --- [nio-2020-exec-4] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-CHECKOUT-SERVICE
2019-10-06 11:11:25.157 INFO 26980 --- [nio-2020-exec-4] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer : Client: CHECKOUT-SERVICE instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=CHECKOUT-SERVICE,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2019-10-06 11:11:25.167 INFO 26980 --- [nio-2020-exec-4] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2019-10-06 11:11:25.215 INFO 26980 --- [nio-2020-exec-4] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty : Flipping property: CHECKOUT-SERVICE.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2019-10-06 11:11:25.218 INFO 26980 --- [nio-2020-exec-4] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client CHECKOUT-SERVICE initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=CHECKOUT-SERVICE,current list of Servers=[192.168.0.6:8098],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone; Instance count:1; Active connections count: 0; Circuit breaker tripped count: 0; Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:192.168.0.6:8098; Zone:defaultZone; Total Requests:0; Successive connection failure:0; Total blackout seconds:0; Last connection made:Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969; First connection made: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969; Active Connections:0; total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0; 90 percentile resp time:0.0; 95 percentile resp time:0.0; min resp time:0.0; max resp time:0.0; stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@6f7f7ca0
2019-10-06 11:11:26.177 INFO 26980 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty : Flipping property: CHECKOUT-SERVICE.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys it was a mistake from my side in resolving the API path